# Importing shapefiles with other CRS other than Web Mercator and WGS84_latlon

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, coordinates

New to Blender.
I have correctly installed and activated the BlenderGIS and the bpyproj addons. The GIS module allows me to add a new CRS searching by the EPSG number when I try to import the shp. However, when I select that CRS, in my case is GDA2020 / MGA zone 56 (EPSG: 7856) and hit ok, Blender returns "Shapefile import fails, check logs" error - upon checking the logs, a Python error pops up which does not help me.

How can I add a shapefile with a specific CRS?

I am using Blender ver 2.90.1 | Windows 10

EDIT: Here is what I do\see:

[image]

Thank you

Comment: I have tried some shp with that projection and I worked for me. Could you share a piece of your layer ?

Comment: @CésarArquero here: https://we.tl/t-8fbMMjGz2B

Answer (score 0):

I've checked your shp and It seems ok. The GIS importation has any problem if you do this:

Check the shp first to be sure about the projection:
[image]

To add some elements of reference to this piece, I've created a point layer to get some perspective:
[image]

Then I've imported the point into the scene just using web mercator (dont worry for the moment as the projection of these will be ok with your layer...)

CRITICAL PART: Now, I've imported your shp using your CRS...BUT...when you specify other than Web mercator, I mean, a defined CRS (7856 in this case), you have to remove the Scene georeferencing...
[image]

...to see something like this:
[image]

Doing so Blender has no problem to locate all the elements within the scene. As you can see, they are correctly positioned to each other. Here is just a view of the points and your line (shp):

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but apart from importing a point shp beforehand (which is out of my scope) I am not doing anything different from you. I do delete the scene georeferencing, yet, it still says "Shapefile import fails, check logs".
I am wondering what am I doing differently from you?